# CSS background-image and some divisions don't work

Tags: css, html

I'm really having a very bad time with this, my background-image isn't working.
This is my CSS file:

```
body
        {
            background-image:url('college_monitor.jpg');
            background-position:left center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size:contain;
        }
```

Image is in the same folder as the html and css files.

Also some of my css divisions don't work fine, this is my css of the divisions:

```
#FullName
        {
            margin-top:10px;
            margin-left:400px;
        }
        #FirstName
        {
            font-size:0.9em;
            color: cornflowerblue;
            border: 2px solid lime;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 20px; 
            width: 150px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #FatherName
        {
            font-size:0.9em;
            color: cornflowerblue;
            border: 2px solid lime;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 20px; 
            width: 150px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #LastName
        {
            font-size:0.9em;
            color: cornflowerblue;
            border: 2px solid lime;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 20px; 
            width: 150px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #Diploma
        {
            margin-left:400px;
            font-size:0.9em;
            color: cornflowerblue;
            border: 2px solid lime;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 20px; 
            width: 150px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #HighSchool
        {
            margin-left:400px;
            font-size:0.9em;
            color: cornflowerblue;
            border: 2px solid lime;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 20px; 
            width: 150px;
            text-align:center;
        }
```

and html file:

```
<div id="FullName">
                        <div id="FirstName"><b><h3>First name:</h3></b></div>
                            <input  class="input" maxlength="10" name="first" type="text" value="" size="30" />

                        <div id="FatherName"><label><b><h3>Father name:</h3></b></div>
                            <input  class="input" maxlength="10" name="father" type="text" value="" size="30" />
                        <div id="LastName"><b><h3>Last name:</h3></b></div>
                            <input  class="input" maxlength="10" name="last" type="text" value="" size="30" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="Uni">
                        <div  id="Diploma"><h3>Diploma:</h3></b></div> 
                        <input type="radio" name="where" value="sv" size="30" /> sv
                        <input type="radio" name="where" value="sg" size="30" /> sg
                        <input type="radio" name="where" value="se" size="30" /> se
                        <input type="radio" name="where" value="lh" size="30" /> lh
                        <input type="radio" name="where" value="freshman" size="30" /> freshman


                        <div  id="HighSchool"><b><h3>High School:</h3></b></div>
                            <input  class="input" maxlength="10" name="hight" type="text" value="" size="30" />
```

The "margin-left" don't work in the diploma and high school divisions
What's wrong with my code?
Thanks,
Johny

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean to you?

Comment: background image isn't appearing

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct? How are you sure? Make sure it is being loaded correctly

Comment: 100% sure of the path, and it's in the same folder also

Comment: @JohnyHimmler Try to check the console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS:

```css
#Diploma {
    margin-left: 400px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    border: 2px solid lime;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 20px; 
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`margin: 20px` overrides `margin-left: 400px;`it means margin 20px in all directions. If you are looking for a quick solution, just add `#Uni` after `#FullName` like this.

```css
#FullName, #Uni {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:400px;
}
```

For the background problem I've created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/10yvzxj8/), if worked fine with my image. If HTML your provided is all your HTML code, then you should probably add `<body></body>` tag to it. If it still doesn't work, there must be something wrong with the image file, try to regenerate it or use another file.

BTW, you should really prettify your HTML/CSS code (at least indent it properly).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96621/discussion-on-answer-by-nostophilia-css-background-image-and-some-divisions-don).

Comment: @Nostophilia Thanks brother, how can I display 2 images in the same place and display for each 3 seconds one of them, then display the second one. I want also a style of this transition like fade or push or wipe like on power point. Thanks very much, Johny.

Comment: @Nostophilia I'm new to programming a little bit so if you can explain each step of this jQuery because I didn't understood it. I really apologize for being annoying. For the chat section, I don't know how the notification and tags work in it, if you have any idea plz tell me cause "Comments are not for extended discussion" at the moderator point of view. I posted this message here and in the chat section so tell me where did you see it.Thanks again.